# Meteor.user() is null when trying to check user login status

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to show other some user's profile page to non-logged in and logged-in users. The problem is that whenever I check

```
if(Meteor.user() === me)
```

*Meteor.user()* returns *null* and code crashes since no one is logged in. How can I check whether there are logged in users?

Comment: Try using `me === Meteor.user()`. Having a constant as the first parameter (I am assuming `me` is a constant) avoids the code to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know:

```
if (Meteor.user()) {
    // code for login user
} else {
    // code for non-login user
}
```

Comment: I don't know how i missed that null check. Long day; thank you yudap